# Page permissions, user group ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, restrictions

I have a post system where all users in the same group can see the same post and edit the same post. But i have a problem with if i for example is editing a post and my friend do edit the same post, then will either i or my friend lose the change we just made and it is only the content last saved their count.

So my question is:
Is there some way i can restrict two users from the same group to see the same post at time.
So if i for example is editing a post and my friend press edit on the post im in he will get a message(Nicolai is editing this post, wait until he is done) and when i leave the edit page he and others from the same group I'm in will be able to edit the post again. But only one at time.

I'm using Ruby on rails 4 and devise for user registration.

I got no idea how to make this.
Hope someone can give me an idea or some inspiration to make this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to take a look at Optimistic and Pessimistic locking from Active Record: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html

this can help you protect the system from bugs caused by accessing the same records simultaneously but does not solve the problem of user not being able to actually open the edit page.

simple solution would be to set a flag (column in db) that will set the lock on the record. you update the lock on accessing edit page and clear on saving. how does that sound?

Comment: That sound interesting. I will defiantly read up on that. Thanks for the link. But i might have another solution ready soon. There will warn the new user if a user all ready is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a railscasts subscription the following is a good resource on optimistic locking. It's not exactly what you want, but a less intrusive alternative [optimistic locking](http://railscasts.com/episodes/59-optimistic-locking-revised)

Another option would be [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) . This would allow you use active record to actually lock the db record. Then you could check for a lock on that record to disable an edit button (or something similar). It'll be more work to accomplish, but sounds like pessimistic locking is what you would like.

Answer (score 0):

SASS for edit.html.haml

```
.editingback
  position: absolute
  width: 100%
  height: 102%
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  z-index: 500
  display: none

.editing
  z-index: 501
  width: 300px
  height: 150px
  background: #eee
  border: 1px solid #adadad
  border-radius: 3px
  position: absolute
  top: 40%
  left: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  font-family: $la
  padding: 15px
  text-align: center
  font-size: 13px
  display: none

#editing_button
  border: 1px solid #eee
  background: #383838
  color: white
  padding: 7px
```

edit.html.haml

```
.editingback
.editing
  = @post.state
  is editing this post at the moment, please try again later!
  %br
  %br
  = link_to 'OK', posts_path, id: 'editing_button'

= form_for (@post) do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.text_area :content
  = f.submit 'Create'

:javascript
  var pageid = '<%= @post.id %>';
  var statevalue = '<%= @post.state %>';
  var currentuser = '<%= current_user.email %>';

  window.onload = checkstate();


  function checkstate() {
  if (statevalue == "") { // If statevalue is equal to "" it will send a ajax request to the updatestate action with the posts id. //
    $.ajax({ 
        url : '/posts/changestate/' + pageid,
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#changenotestate').serialize(),
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = removestate; // When the user leave the site will it run the removestate function to remove state //
  } else if (statevalue != currentuser) { // If a new user enter the page after you and the statevalue not is equal to the currentuser, show the warning //
    $(".editingback").show();
    $(".editing").fadeIn(2000);
  } else {

  }
  };

  // A function there will send a ajax request to the removestate action //
  function removestate(){
  $.ajax({
        url : '/posts/removestate/' + pageid,
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#changenotestate').serialize(),
  });
  };
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def edit ## Edit post action
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update ## Update post action
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def updatestate ## Action there will add current_user.email to the state field 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update(:state => current_user.email)
    redirect_to :back
end

def removestate ## Action there will remove current_user.email to the state field
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update(:state => '')
    redirect_to :back
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :posts # RESTFULL ROUTES
post '/posts/changestate/:id' => 'posts', :action => 'updatestate' #ROUTE TO UPDATE POST STATE
post '/posts/removestate/:id' => 'posts', :action => 'removestate' # ROUTE TO REMOVE POST STATE
```

posts table has the following fields:

Id, Title, Content, State.

---

I do really like this solution but all it actually do is to warn the user that another user already is editing the post he wanted to edit.

So the user can just use he's browsers "control element" function to remove the warning.
Therefore will i look into "pessimistic locking" to make it secure.

Enjoy.. and please tell me if you know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may take a look at [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) and they [implementation in Ruby with Redis](https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore/).

By using them you can restrict access to only one person at a time (however you'll have to write all logic by yourself) - redis gave you pretty good tool, [atomic operations](http://redis.io/commands/INCR).